# chromedriver 2.29 /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./chromedriver)

Tags: google-chrome, centos, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using chromedriver with https://chrome.richardlloyd.org.uk/ solution for my CentOS 6.6 machine and found that for chromedriver 2.29 it is asking for GLIBC_2.14, but for 2.28 it is not. Is it an issue or jus as planned ?

Kernel: 2.6.32-573.26.1.el6.x86_64

Libstdc:

```
[mdvoryanchenko@serv ~]$ strings /opt/google/chrome/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep -e 'GLIBC*'
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```